# Javascript - Update Object Keys Based Another Object's Value Mapping

Tags: javascript

I am working with two objects, `data` and `map`, in which I need to update the keys of the `data` object with the `text` value of the `map` object based on the key of `data` matching the value of the `datafield` key within the `map` object.

```
data = [{
  1230c9299007b07bf73bb396: "Current",
  5900c9299007b07bf73bb3a0: "Will",
  5900c9299007b07bf73bb39f: "Johnson"
}, {
  1230c9299007b07bf73bb396: "Current",
  5900c9299007b07bf73bb3a0: "Donna",
  5900c9299007b07bf73bb39f: "Sampson"
}, {
  1230c9299007b07bf73bb396: "Past",
  5900c9299007b07bf73bb3a0: "Frank",
  5900c9299007b07bf73bb39f: "Lloyd"
}];

map = [{
  dataField: "1230c9299007b07bf73bb396",
  text: "Customer Type"
}, {
  dataField: "5900c9299007b07bf73bb3a0",
  text: "First Name"
}, {
  dataField: "5900c9299007b07bf73bb39f",
  text: "Last Name"
}];
```

Expected result:

```
result = [{
  "Customer Type": "Current",
  "First Name": "Will",
  "Last Name": "Johnson"
}, {
  "Customer Type": "Current",
  "First Name": "Donna",
  "Last Name": "Sampson"
}, {
  "Customer Type": "Past",
  "First Name": "Frank",
  "Last Name": "Lloyd"
}];
```

I have attempted with the following code only to find the two objects merge and do not update any of the object keys as expected:

```
let items = Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
  const newKey = map[key] || key;
  return { [newKey] : data[key] };
});
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but note that object keys cannot begin with a number.  (`1230c9299007b07bf73bb396`, etc. need to be in quotes.)

Comment: `Object.keys(data)` are the indices of the array. Notice your map is used on the array. I think you meant to loop through the data array and then for each  object compare the key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voilà.

```js
var data = [{
  "1230c9299007b07bf73bb396": "Current",
  "5900c9299007b07bf73bb3a0": "Will",
  "5900c9299007b07bf73bb39f": "Johnson"
}, {
  "1230c9299007b07bf73bb396": "Current",
  "5900c9299007b07bf73bb3a0": "Donna",
  "5900c9299007b07bf73bb39f": "Sampson"
}, {
  "1230c9299007b07bf73bb396": "Past",
  "5900c9299007b07bf73bb3a0": "Frank",
  "5900c9299007b07bf73bb39f": "Lloyd"
}];

var map = [{
  dataField: "1230c9299007b07bf73bb396",
  text: "Customer Type"
}, {
  dataField: "5900c9299007b07bf73bb3a0",
  text: "First Name"
}, {
  dataField: "5900c9299007b07bf73bb39f",
  text: "Last Name"
}];  


let items = data.map(object => {
  let newObj = {};
  map.forEach(prop => newObj[prop.text] = object[prop.dataField]);
  return newObj;
});

console.log(items);
```

Hope it answers

Comment: I posted pretty much the same answer a couple minutes after you did.  Now deleted, and +1.

Comment: This one really seems to be the best solution so far.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the votes, but the system moderators will probably remove them since they came so quickly.  Best to vote up answers only if they help you.

Comment: @RickHitchcock hope they don't notice

Comment: You may not want to risk their wrath.  I have no problem if you remove the upvotes : )

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```js
const pre = document.getElementById('pre');

const data = [{
    '1230c9299007b07bf73bb396': "Current",
    '5900c9299007b07bf73bb3a0': "Will",
    '5900c9299007b07bf73bb39f': "Johnson"
  },
  {
    '1230c9299007b07bf73bb396': "Current",
    '5900c9299007b07bf73bb3a0': "Donna",
    '5900c9299007b07bf73bb39f': "Sampson"
  },
  {
    '1230c9299007b07bf73bb396': "Past",
    '5900c9299007b07bf73bb3a0': "Frank",
    '5900c9299007b07bf73bb39f': "Lloyd"
  }
];

const map = [{
  dataField: "1230c9299007b07bf73bb396",
  text: "Customer Type"
}, {
  dataField: "5900c9299007b07bf73bb3a0",
  text: "First Name"
}, {
  dataField: "5900c9299007b07bf73bb39f",
  text: "Last Name"
}];

const fieldToText = map.reduce((result, el) => {
  result[el.dataField] = el.text;
  return result
}, []);

const result = data.map((el) => {
  return Object.entries(el).reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
    result[fieldToText[key]] = value;
    return result;
  }, {});
});

pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oniondomes/gqgkroux/

Comment: Op should note how @oniondomes converts the `map` to something that's a real map (`fieldToText`). If you have control of this, you should have your map in this structure to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

At first build up a number - key map:

```
  const keys = new Map(map.map({dataField, text}) => ([dataField, text])));
```

Now you can map every data entry to a new object by iterating over all the key value pairs abd building new objects:

```
  const result = data.map(obj => {
    const tmp = {};
    for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)){
      tmp[keys.get(key) || "_"] = value;
    }
    return tmp;
 });
```